# How to refactor this with Stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can refactor this with java stream?

```
List<SessionCreateParams.LineItem> elements = new ArrayList<>();
SessionCreateParams.LineItem lineItem;

for (Product product : experience.getProducts()) {
    String taxRate = getTaxRate(product.getPriceId());
    lineItem = stripeProxy.createLineItem(1L, product.getPriceId(), taxRate);
    elements.add(lineItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Stream over the products, convert each product to a `LineItem` and collect to a `List`.

```
List<SessionCreateParams.LineItem> elements =
    experience.getProducts()
              .stream()
              .map(p -> stripeProxy.createLineItem(1L, p.getPriceId(), 
                                                   getTaxRate(p.getPriceId())))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```